# How to improve a function that "slice using a list"

Tags: python, slice

my function is using a list as the indices for a slice

```
slice_ = [1, 2, 0]  # start, stop, step
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I want to write more elegant code

```
def slice_function(slice_target, slice_: list[int]):
    if len(slice_) == 0:
        slice_target = slice_target

    if len(slice_) == 1:
        stop, = slice_
        slice_target = slice_target[stop]

    if len(slice_) == 2:
        start, stop = slice_
        slice_target = slice_target[start:stop]

    if len(slice_) == 3:
        start, stop, step = slice_
        slice_target = slice_target[start:stop:step]

    return slice_target
```

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate function instead of just slicing the array dirrectly?

Comment: Only the len==0 case needs to be handled specially.  All the rest can be handled by `slice_target[slice(*_slice)]`.

Comment: Side note, having step 0 like in your example `slice_` would throw `ValueError: slice step cannot be zero`.

Comment: @jasonharper. hi, I want to get the value like `my_list[index]`. when `slice_` has only one value, `slice_target[slice(*_slice)]` will return a list

Comment: @Rayan Hatout. hi, I will get the `slice_` from a json. and the `slice_` is an array in json

Comment: You can make a slice from an array like this: `slice_obj = slice(*slice_)`. Then you can use this directly, like `["a", "b"][slice_obj]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to get it much shorter than this:

```
def slice_function(slice_target, slice_: list[int]):
    if len(slice_) == 0:
        return slice_target
    if len(slice_) == 1:
        return slice_target[slice_[0]]
    return slice_target[slice(*slice_)]
```

Comment: This is the best way, because it handles the special 0-element and 1-element cases.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this:

```py
def slice_function(list_to_slice, slice_definition: list[int]):
    try:
        start = slice_definition[0]
    except IndexError:
        return list_to_slice
    try:
        stop = slice_definition[1]
    except IndexError:
        stop = slice_definition[0]+1
    try:
        step = slice_definition[2]
    except IndexError:
        step = 1
    return list_to_slice[start:stop:step]


print(slice_function([1,4,5,6,6,76,6], [1,2,1]))
print(slice_function([1,4,5,6,6,76,6], [1,10,2]))
print(slice_function([1,4,5,6,6,76,6], [3,5]))
print(slice_function([1,4,5,6,6,76,6], [1]))
print(slice_function([1,4,5,6,6,76,6], []))
```